# Function declarations in C++

Tags: c++, function, declaration

I have the following declarations:

```
int a, b, c;
int *p1, *p2, *p3;
char d, str[10], *cp;
float big, r;
```

and I have to supply the proper function declaration. to the following:

```
r = foo(str, &p1, b * c);
str[8] = bazptr( &b, ‘#’, &cp);
pretty( strlen(str), *p2 - 10, str[2] + 3.141, p2 );
```

Like in this example:

```
int go_figure(int a1, char b2);
```

Comment: What are your thoughts? Which ones are you stuck on?

Comment: Sounds great. So go ahead and do it! We won't simply "do it for you".

Comment: I suggest that you read your textbook again, and if you still have trouble with a specific argument, you ask again about the specific part you didn't understand.

Comment: Before reading the *solution* answers, try reading my one. It guides you through the first declaration. You should then be able to solve the others by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'll solve the first one as an example.

```
// Declarations we care about
int b, c;
int *p1;
char str[10];

// Function we need to figure out the signature of
r = foo(str, &p1, b * c);
```

I would start by figuring out the return type:

`r =` tells me that the desired return type will be the type of `r`: the return type is `float`. *(obviously not taking into account possible implicit conversions)*

**So far: `float foo(?...);`**

Then I would count the number of arguments: `str`, `&p1`, `b * c`. Yes, 3 arguments.

**So far: `float foo(?, ?, ?);`**

First argument is `str`. What is the type of `str`? It is `char[]`, which decays to `char*`.

**So far: `float foo(char*, ?, ?);`**

Second argument is `&p1`. It means we're taking the address of `p1`. So it has to be a pointer to whatever type `p1` is. `p1` is an `int*`. Our type will then be `int**`.

**So far: `float foo(char*, int**, ?);`**

Third argument is `b * c`. `b` and `c` are of type `int`. Multiplication between integers evaluates to `int`. Our type will then be `int`.

**So far: `float foo(char*, int**, int);`**

That's it!

Comment: thank you. I was able to do the other ones because of your explanation

Comment: Very glad to hear that. Please attempt exercises on your own before running to StackOverflow, though! Also, you should mark the answer as accepted.